# where to find appengine endpoints.sh script

Tags: java, ios, google-app-engine, backend

I'm trying to generate the client libraries so that I can integrate my client iOS app with my backend. In following the instructions here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#command_line_syntax_for_the_endpoints_tool) I have to generate a discovery document which requires the endpoints.sh script but I have no idea where to download this from. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven you can use the appengine maven plugin.

You can then generate the client library through the maven plugin by running

```
mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib
```